# Aggregate Subquery and then Group By

Tags: sql, count, subquery, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to get a count of children and adults enrolled in programs and then group by household id.

I can easily get the count of *all* clients per household with the following query:

```
SELECT enrollments.id, household.id, COUNT(clients.id) AS client_count
FROM enrollments
INNER JOIN clients ON enrollments.ref_client = clients.id
INNER JOIN household ON enrollments.ref_household = household.id
GROUP BY household.id;
```

My issue is getting counts of adults and children, which is not in the dataset and so must be calculated. My best attempt has been the following:

```
SELECT enrollments.id, household.id,
    (SELECT COUNT(clients.id)
    FROM clients 
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,clients.birth_date,now())<18)
    AS youth_client_count
FROM  enrollments
INNER JOIN clients ON enrollments.ref_client = clients.id
INNER JOIN household ON enrollments.ref_household = household.id
GROUP BY household.id;
```

but because the subquery isn't an aggregate function, it's showing the total count of youth clients for each row instead of grouping by household. I tried putting the subquery into a COUNT() function, but this isn't allowed. How can I count these subsets of clients grouped by household?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for a conditional count:

```
select e.id, h.id, count(c.id) as client_count,
    count(case when timestampdiff(year, c.birth_date, current_date) <  18 then c.id end) children_count,
    count(case when timestampdiff(year, c.birth_date, current_date) >= 18 then c.id end) adult_count
from enrollments e
inner join clients c  on e.ref_client = c.id
inner join household h on e.ref_household = h.id
group by e.id, h.id;
```

The `case` expression within the `count` lets you take in account only clients that satisfy the given condition.

If you are running MySQL, as you seem to, the conditional `count` can be neatened like so:

```
sum(timestampdiff(year, c.birth_date, current_date) < 18) children_count
```

Side notes:

- all non-aggregated columns must appear in the `group by` clause; I added `e.id`, which was missing
- table aliases (`e`, `c`, `h`) make the query easier to write and read

Comment: Really good to see you on the site again `:-)`

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen... Just passing by :)